# Use custom environment properties from Elastic Beanstalk for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to use the custom environment property of elastic beanstalk in htaccess? I only want to rewrite http to https when not running locally so I thought I could do this by using the environment property of elastic beanstalk as a condition.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @gmaniac . I've created a cloudfront distribution to forward the http to https. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score -3):

You can find the solution at below link for similar problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878024/configure-apache-on-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: You might want to copy (some off) the actual details into your post. Because if that link ever breaks then your answer becomes useless.